# Receiving Spam Continuously

Tags: spam

I am continuously receiving Spam even though i have installed "low NoSpam" and "Freeform Anti-Spam" any ideas on how to block this out completely or alternative add-on.. thanks!!!!!

Comment: You don't say what type of spam—comment or registration spam, or both or possibly entry spam if you have forms on the site. Generally, speaking there's no way to completely block spam, but you can reduce it, depending on how it's coming in. But you need to provide more details.

Comment: Sorry, I dont have enough rep to make a comment. I once had spam emails problem with EE. I noticed the index.php in the root folder was modified, looking at the bottom of the file it was all SEO and email script injection. Had to clean that out to prevent further spam. The cause was using outdated phpthumbs script. So just a head up.

Comment: It is from a contact form and it appears like this :: 
"Entry Date: 2013-04-21 02:19

Attachments: 0
Collection Name: Contact Form
Name: ysaelmdd
Email: isvkvd@pifiyh.com
Subject: miwSfRJHLQSf
Phone: LWNCKeKczPbeBLxVWol
Message: Q9G8zL <a href="http://rpnhzafkxesg.com/">rpnhzafkxesg</a>,
[url=http://yjgpwnwxwlqr.com/]yjgpwnwxwlqr[/url],
[link=http://deqszhhgzprs.com/]deqszhhgzprs[/link], http://jtxqdnsqhbte.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you to use Snaptcha (http://www.putyourlightson.net/snaptcha). I had faced such a problem but Snaptcha worked great for me.

Comment: also good honey-pot captcha http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/hon-ee-pot-captcha